# Using Tailwind flex items not able to center

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've 3 flex items which I want to place similar to **instagram login page** ( 1st row - image, login form ) and ( 2nd row - footer )

I've below code

```
<div className='container mx-auto px-4 lg:px-0 flex flex-col max-w-screen-md justify-center items-center'>
  <div className='container mx-auto px-4 lg:px-0 flex flex-row justify-center'>
    <div className='lg:w-3/5 items-center'>
      <p> first </p>
    </div>
    <div className='lg:w-2/5 items-center'>
      <p> second </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='flex'>
    <div className=''>
      <p> third </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to get 1st row items centered, they are aligning to the left.

Please clarify what's going wrong with this logic

Answer (score 2):

```
<div className="container mx-auto px-4 lg:px-0 flex flex-col max-w-screen-md justify-between items-center border-orange-500 border-2">
  <div className="container mx-auto px-4 lg:px-0 flex flex-col items-center">
    <div className="lg:w-3/5 flex justify-center border-2 border-red-500">
      <p> first </p>
    </div>
    <div className="lg:w-2/5 flex flex-row justify-center border-2 border-blue-500">
      <p> second </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="flex border-2 border-green-500">
    <div className="">
      <p> third </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

> I have added borders around the items so they are more easily seen, but the issue was on line 2 with `flex-row justify-center` you need to change it to `flex-col items-center` or change to [`flex-wrap`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-wrap).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com//tailwindcss@2.1.1/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-between min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center flex-1 w-full p-4">
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full max-w-xs p-6 space-y-3 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-sm">
      <p class="self-center mb-4 text-4xl text-gray-900">Login</p>
      <input class="text-xs text-gray-400 bg-gray-50 py-1.5 rounded px-2 border border-gray-200" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <input class="text-xs text-gray-400 bg-gray-50 py-1.5 rounded px-2 border border-gray-200" type="text" placeholder="Password" />
      <button class="py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-white rounded bg-blue-500">Login</button>
    </div>
    <p class="pt-4 text-gray-500">Get the app.</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="p-4 text-sm text-gray-400">Footer</div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/L8rgPEBUPc

Answer (score -3):

I realize it's been 5 months; however,

```
<div className="..." ></div>
```

should be just

```
<div class="..." ></div>
```

Comment: Did you notice that your respond has the className properties hidden?